# Is it possible to package a python application with its separate terminal?

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze

I would like to have an executable (Windows, MacOS, Linux) of my program that will have its own terminal window where users will be able to type in. I don't want to have the user install modules or anything except this executable. You could say that the UI of my program would be a terminal window. Is it possible and with what?

I basically want the GUI of my app to be a terminal window.

Comment: I'm afraid, you would need to create your own GUI for getting user input. What is the problem with using the native terminal of the OS?

Comment: Yes, there are a few different ways of achieving the result you're looking for. The "how" aspect is off topic: It's too broad, and Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials or documentation.

Comment: I haven't found anything on how to have a terminal as UI. There are information on freezing the application but they usually assume that you have a GUI made.

Comment: That is why I asked, why not just use the native console/terminal of the OS? All OS comes with a built-in console/terminal, users don't need to install anything. See [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423214/2745495).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a command-line interface for your program you'll likely want to use something like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), which is in the standard Python library. There are many other feature-rich command-line interface modules (e.g., click) you could try to use instead. You can design command-line interactions for your users including input and output, menus, etc.

Once you've built your application, a good choice to make it portable is the [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) module. If you set the *--onefile* option when invoking it, it will generate a single .exe file which can be easily shared with users. If you also set the *--console* option when invoking PyInstaller, then your Python .exe application will interface with stdin/stdout. On Windows, this would be a cmd window.

If a user invokes your .exe via the GUI (e.g., a double-click on its icon), a Windows CMD window will be opened. If you want that window to *stay* open, however, you will need to create your application with some kind of "infinite"/"captive" design that never finishes executing until the user explicitly quits.

If the user instead runs the .exe from a Windows CMD terminal that is already open, then that window will always stay open.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add additional clarity and context.

Comment: Right, `argparse` doesn't create the GUI or terminal window. It's a tool for designing and managing the input/output experience for the user.

It's the use of the `--console` option when building your .exe with PyInstaller that ensures that the stdin/stdout from your Python application actually displays in a CMD window.

Comment: Thanks this adds much needed clarity. I will try what you said. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're looking for curses, or UniCurses if you're stuck with Microsoft Windows.

Many terminal emulators will allow you to start them up with a command line option that specifies a command to run in that emulator instead of your default shell.